# How to arrange 2 lists in 2 grids of equal number of columns?

Tags: algorithm, user-interface

I have 2 lists of icons, that need to be arranged in 2 grids.

How do I work out the number of columns for the grids, so that

1. in each grid there are an equal number of columns.
2. The number of rows is irrelevant.
3. The columns should not exceed a maximum (e.g. 6 columns)
4. The display is a wide desktop monitor, so a wide grid is preferred over a long grid (see example below)

Example 1

- list1: 7 items
- list2: 4 items
- => use 4 columns,
- list1 2 rows by 4 columns (2nd row only partially full),
- list2 1 row by 4 columns
  [image: 7 and 4 items]

Example 2

- list1: 100 items
- list2: 5 items
- => use 5 columns,
- list1: 20 rows by 5
- list2: 1 row by 5 columns

Example 3 (Wide grid vs. long grid)

- list1: 2 items
- list2: 8 items
- =>
- Long grid: 2 columns in each grid (not preferred)
- Wide grid: e.g. 4 columns in each grid (preferred)
  [image: preferred vs not preferred]

Here is my attempt in C#. There are comments in the code but basically there are 3 steps.

1. For each icon-list get a list of all possible columns (i.e. 1 up to the length of the shortest icon-list)
2. Find the best column in both lists (i.e. where the difference between the columns is smallest)
3. Because there could be multiple best columns, find the best-best column

   ```
   public int GetIdealNumColumns(int s1, int s2)
   {
       const int maxCol = 6; //maximum number of columns
       if (s1 == s2) { return maxCol; }

       //STEP 1 -------------------------------------------------
       //get all possible columns for both lists
       int gcd = GCD(s1, s2);
       int range = Math.Min(Math.Min(s1, s2),maxCol);
       var cols1 = Enumerable.Range(1, range).ToList();
       var cols2 = Enumerable.Range(1, range).ToList();
       // -------------------------------------------------

       //STEP 2 -------------------------------------------------
       //go through both lists and find the best #columns -> this is N^2            
       int bestDiff = int.MaxValue;
       //there could be multiple equal column numbers between the 2 lists
       //so use 2 lists to store the results
       List<int> bestCols1 = new List<int>();
       List<int> bestCols2 = new List<int>();
       for (int i1 = 0; i1 < cols1.Count; i1++)
       {
           for (int i2 = 0; i2 < cols2.Count; i2++)
           {

               //difference between the number of columns
               int diff = Math.Abs(cols1[i1] - cols2[i2]);

               //the smaller the difference the better
               if (diff < bestDiff)
               {
                   bestDiff = diff;

                   //reset the lists
                   bestCols1 = new List<int>();
                   bestCols2 = new List<int>();

                   bestCols1.Add(i1);
                   bestCols2.Add(i2);
               }
               else if (diff == bestDiff) //difference equal => store
               {
                   bestCols1.Add(i1);
                   bestCols2.Add(i2);
               }
           }
       }
       // -------------------------------------------------

       //STEP 3 -------------------------------------------------
       //now go through the best results and find the result that
       //is closest to the max-number-of-columns
       bestDiff = int.MaxValue;
       int best = 0;
       if (bestCols1.Count > 1)
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < bestCols1.Count; i++)
           {
               //get average value
               int avg = (cols1[bestCols1[i]] + cols2[bestCols2[i]]) / 2;

               //check how close the maxCol
               int diff = Math.Abs(avg - maxCol);
               if (diff < bestDiff)
               {
                   bestDiff = diff;
                   best = cols1[bestCols1[i]]; //not sure if I should take avg?
               }
           }
       }
       // -------------------------------------------------

       return best == 0 ? maxCol : best;

   }
   ```

Comment: why in your 3rd example you go with the 4 columns instead of 6 columns?

Comment: yes, from what I wrote, it should be 6 by 2, but I has hoping this algorithm would return 4 by 4 (looks better)